# How to change dynamic private IP address in a virtual network to static (non-changing) IP address for containergroups (Azure Container Instances)

Tags: static, containers, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-instances, virtual-network

I currently have a containergroup that uses a virtual network to communicate. What happens is that from time to time the dynamic IP changes randomly. I know it is not possible to have a public (non-changing) IP address using a FQDN for the time being (Azure is working on it), but I was wondering if there is a way to change the IP address from dynamic to static. Any other workaround would be fine too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The short answer is no.  If the reply could answer your question, please consider accepting it,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, currently, the ACI does not provide the ability to assign a static private IP address to the container when using a private VNet. See https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances/suggestions/36989110-allow-aci-instances-to-use-a-static-ip-address-whe.

So you could upvote that feedback so that the Azure team might improve the ACI service.